# Type casting failure in C program

Tags: c

As a C fresher, I am trying to write a recursive routine to convert a decimal number to the equivalent binary. However, the resultant string is not correct in the output. I think it has to be related to the Type casting from int to char. Not able to find a satisfactory solution. Can anyone help? Thanx in advance.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int decimal, counter=0;
char* binary_string = (char*)calloc(65, sizeof(char));

void decimal_to_binary(int);

int main()
{

    puts("\nEnter the decimal number : ");
    scanf("%d", &decimal);
    
    decimal_to_binary(decimal);
    *(binary_string + counter) = '\0';

    printf("Counter = %d\n", counter);
    puts("The binary equivalent is : ");
    puts(binary_string);
    return 0;
}

void decimal_to_binary(int number)
{
    if (number == 0)
        return;
    else
    {
        int temp = number % 2;
        decimal_to_binary(number/2);
        *(binary_string + counter) = temp;
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Should the casting store only the LSB of int in the char array each time?

Comment: What is the result? Is there an error? What do you expect? Please try to be complete.

Comment: You can write `calloc` outside of a function?

Comment: You're (eventually) printing a byte array filled with `0`s and `1`s (the `0`s are the *famous* string terminator). Try adding `'0'` before adding to `binary_string` : `*(binary_string + counter) = temp + '0';` ... **and remember to add a proper string terminator**.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

int decimal, counter=0;

//char* binary_string = (char*)calloc(65, sizeof(char));

//C does not allow initialization of global variables with
//non constant values. Instead declare a static char array with 65 elements.
//Alternatively declare binary_string in the main function and allocate memory with calloc.
char binary_string[65];

void decimal_to_binary(int);

int main()
{
    puts("\nEnter the decimal number : ");
    scanf("%d", &decimal);

    decimal_to_binary(decimal);
    //*(binary_string + counter) = '\0';
    // This is more readable:
    binary_string[counter] = '\0';

    printf("Counter = %d\n", counter);
    puts("The binary equivalent is : ");
    puts(binary_string);
    return 0;
}

void decimal_to_binary(int number)
{
    if (number == 0)
        return;
    else
    {
        int temp = number % 2;
        //decimal_to_binary(number/2);
        //you call decimal_to_binary again before increasing counter.
        //That means every time you call decimal_to_binary, the value of count
        //is 0 and you always write to the first character in the string.

        //*(binary_string + counter) = temp;
        //This is more readable
        //binary_string[counter] = temp;
        //But you are still setting the character at position counter to the literal value temp, which is either 0 or 1.
        //if its 0, you are effectively writing a \0 (null character) which in C represents the end of a string.
        //You want the *character* that represents the value of temp.
        //in ASCII, the value for the *character* 0 is 0x30 and for 1 it is 0x31.
        binary_string[counter] = 0x30 + temp;
        counter++;

        //Now after writing to the string and incrementing counter, you can call decimal_to_binary again
        decimal_to_binary(number/2);
    }
}
```

If you compile this, run the resulting executable and enter 16 as a number, you may expect to get `10000` as output. But you get`00001`. Why is that?
You are writing the binary digits to the string in the wrong order.
The first binary digit you calculate is the least significant  bit, which you write to the first character in the string etc.
To fix that aswell, you can do:

```
void decimal_to_binary(int number){
    if(number == 0){
        return;
    }
    else{
        int temp = number % 2;
        counter++;
        //Store the position of the current digit
        int pos = counter;
        //Don't write it to the string yet
        decimal_to_binary(number/2);
        //Now we know how many characters are needed and we can fill the string
        //in reverse order. The first digit (where pos = 1) goes to the last character in the string (counter - pos). The second digit (where pos = 2) goes to the second last character in the string etc.
        binary_string[counter - pos] = 0x30 + temp;
    } 
}
```

This is not the most efficient way, but it is closest to your original solution.
Also note that this breaks for negative numbers (consider `decimal = -1`, `-1 % 2 = -1`).

Comment: very poor implementation depending on the side effects.

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not use global variables if not absolutely necessary. Changing the global variable in the function makes it very not universal.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *tobin(char *buff, unsigned num)
{
    if(num / 2) buff = tobin(buff, num / 2);
    buff[0] = '0' + num % 2;
    buff[1] = 0;
    return buff + 1;
}



int main(void)
{
    char buff[65];
    unsigned num = 0xf1;
    
    tobin(buff, num);
    
    printf("%s\n", buff);
}
```